# Uncaught ReferenceError google is not defined when using google g

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, google-api, react-component

I use react, and want to use one tap google social login.
So,

```
//index.html
...
<title>React App</title>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
...

// App.js
/* global google */
import ...
class App extends Component{
 constructor(props){
google.accounts.id.initialize({client_id:'1234-acd.apps.googleusercontent.com'})
console.log("google",google)
console.log("google account", google.accounts)
console.log("google account id",google.accounts.id)
google.accounts.id.prompt(notification =>{
console.log('on prompt notification', notification)
})
}
```

but it occurs - Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

I delete cookie and restart it, it works very well but only once.

In chrome secret mode, it doesn't work even once.

Comment: Hello @dojung, some progress with this issue? Something similar happens to me in the implementation of Google Identity Services Login. It happens to me that if I refresh several times it shows me the following error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wait for google SDK script to load so it can inject google property in window object. after that initialize google login.

You can use [@react-oauth/google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google) which is a small layer around new google service identity SDK, will help you alot

Comment: Hello, I tried and unfortunately I still have the same error